# starting h2o in R hangs

Tags: r, h2o

I've installed h2o in R and when I run the command:

```
h2o.init()
```

the R console completely hangs with no message at all being given. I have to restart R in order to get out of this.

If I run `java -jar h2o.jar` in the command prompt and it ends with `cloud of size 2 formed [/172.17.132.30:54323, /172.17.132.30:54325]`

so I then tried to run `h2o.init(port = 54323)` and it seems to work fine.

However, when I try to do demo's e.g. `demo(h2o.kmeans)` it starts the demo in `localhost\54321` which doesn't exist. My question is:

Why doesn't the usual port 54321 work? What does the message `cloud of size 2 formed [/172.17.132.30:54323, /172.17.132.30:54325]` mean and why is there 2 ports? How do I set it to default to a working port from R directly as it seems to be able to find the correct port using the `java -jar h2o.jar` command? How can I get the `demo(h2o.kmeans)` to work with the correct port?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that java process was still running( and holding port 54321) as restarting R(RStudio) does not kill it. Following attempts to start `h2o` from the console by default were choosing next available ports ( 54323, 54325).

If demo script has port being specified in `h2o.init()` it makes it a requirement to either connect to `h2o` process running on this port or to launch a new one on this port. Hanged process was an obstacle for both scenarios.

So one solution is to find hanged process and kill it or change port in the demo script to a free one ( or just don't specify it as by default it will launch `h2o` at a next available port).